# aws start-session end with **Cannot perform start session: EOF**

Tags: aws-ssm, aws-session-manager

I try to using Session Manager within my CI (with a vanilla configuration, so nothing too fancy).

All inputs (keys, etc.) and configurations (user/strategy/key) are valid. I succeed to start a session on my own laptop.

But on my pipeline i got the following message

```
Starting session with SessionId: xxxx-xxxxxxx
$ **Cannot perform start session: EOF**
```

Is this shell related ?

For reference, tools used on the CI :

- Session Manager plugin : 1.2.30.0
- AWS CLI : aws-cli/1.18.223 Python/2.7.17 Linux/5.4.0-1039-azure botocore/1.19.63

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I'm having the same issue. My case is I'm running `aws ecs execute-command` from github action.

Comment: @BenjaminHao Yes, it's simply related to TTY. At the end we reserved start-session for SSHing through laptops. For our CD we're using `aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript"` and a script executed remotly (on EC2 on our case, not ECS). Regards

Comment: Thanks! I will try your solution. I found another one that worked for me. I installed `expect` by `sudo apt-get install expect` and run the command using `unbuffer aws ecs execute-command .... `

Comment: @BenjaminHao It's clever, since unbuffer allow to bypass the interactive behavior ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you bumped into this error like I did:

```
Cannot perform start session: EOF
```

and got here, then using the information from Benjamin Hao's comment, here are the steps I took to make it finally work:

Install expect, in my case I had to install it on the Github hosted runner which is installed with Ubuntu:

```
apt install -y expect
```

Then, add "unbuffer" before the command you're trying to execute, for example:

```
unbuffer aws ecs execute-command --region $REGION --cluster $ecs_cluster_name --task $ecs_task_id --container ops-machine --command 'clitool env start --confirm' --interactive
```

Comment: [This issue posted with SSM coves this as well.](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/354)

Answer (score 0):

For `aws ssm` command i used the `AWS-StartInteractiveCommand` option in --document-name

```
aws ssm start-session --document-name 'AWS-StartInteractiveCommand' --parameters '{"command": ["some_command"]}' --target ${ec2_instance_id}
```

With this, you don't need to install expect